# Gyroscope Bandwidth on LSM9DS1

Tags: sensor, bandwidth, imu, gyroscope

I am trying to read data at 119Hz and above from the gyroscope embedded in the LSM9DS1 9dof IMU package and transfer the raw data from the gyroscope to an Android device. On the Android, I plan to use this data along with the accelerometer and magnetometer data to calculate roll, pitch, yaw, and xyz position.

I was wondering about one of the setting on the gyro, called the bandwidth. I read from a few [sources](http://www.sensorwiki.org/doku.php/sensors/gyroscope)  that this refers to the read rate of the gyro, but for this sensor the ODR tells me the output data rate. The ODR goes much higher than the bandwidth. Is the bandwidth a lowpass filter applied to the sensor data before being collected by the ADC? That seems to be what is suggested in this [data sheet](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/12/98/b4/44/a5/bf/4e/c5/DM00157511.pdf/files/DM00157511.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00157511.pdf) in section 2.6, although this is describing the accelerometer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check section 2.7 of the datasheet.

The bandwidth (actually, the cutoff of the low pass filter) is automatically set depending the the output data rate (ODR) that you select.  There is a chart (actually two, as it also depends on the power save mode) that shows the cut off frequencies for the various ODRs.

The datasheet is written bit strangely.  The text keeps talking about "bandwidth" when the tables are all about "cutoffs."

Since the LSM9DS1 also has a high pass filter, the bandwidth would be the difference between the selected highpass and low pass filters.